# How to setup a multipage project with fuse-box?

Tags: bundle

I'm not able to import files in my fusebox project and keep seeing the following error:

> GET http://localhost:4444/hello.ts 404 (Not Found)

I've set my import statements correctly and don't understand what's causing the error. My project structure looks like this:

[image]

The config file:

```
Sparky.task("config", () => {
    fuse = FuseBox.init({
        homeDir: "src",
        output: "dist/$name.js",
        hash: isProduction,
        sourceMaps: !isProduction,
        plugins: [
            [SassPlugin(), CSSPlugin()],
            CSSPlugin(),
            WebIndexPlugin({ 
                target: "index.html",
                template: "src/index.html"
            }),
            WebIndexPlugin({ 
                target: "login.html",
                template: "src/login.html"
            }),
            isProduction && UglifyJSPlugin()
        ],

    });  

    // vendor should come first
    vendor = fuse.bundle("vendor")
        .instructions("~ js/indexView.ts"); 

    // out main bundle
    app = fuse.bundle("app")
        .instructions(`!> js/indexView.ts`);

    if (!isProduction) {
        fuse.dev();
    }
});
```

Hello.ts:

```
export function hello(name: string) {
    return `Hello ${name}`;
}
```

IndexView.ts:

```
import {hello} from "./hello.ts";

const message: string = `This is the index page`;
console.log(hello(message));
```

You can also find this project [here on Github](https://github.com/stijnvanlieshout/fusebox-multipage-test).

Comment: this question is still unanswered!